# custom route for <Resource> component

Tags: admin-on-rest

I like to create a new custom route for user resource, like /:id/passreset maps to the passreset component, similar to /user/:id/delete

This /passreset will open up a dialog like /delete and ask for the confirmation.

What I did:

- Add customRoutes:

  ```
  <Route exact path="/users/:id/passreset" component={ActionChangePassword} />
  ```
- Create new button with:

  ```
  containerElement={<Link to={`${linkToRecord(basePath, record.id)}/passreset`} />}
  ```
- Create a new action and copy content from admin-on-rest\src\mui\delete\Delete.js

However, it is not working properly. Keep getting an error below. Please advise.

Thanks!

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]
    src/actionPassReset.js:123
      120 | function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
      121 |     return {
      122 |         id: decodeURIComponent(props.match.params.id),
    > 123 |         data:                                                 state.admin[props.resource].data[decodeURIComponent(props.match.params.id)]        ,
      124 |         isLoading: state.admin.loading > 0,
      125 |     };
      126 | }
```

Comment: Console.log props.resource and see what is happening. This seems like a bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the state has been reorganized in 1.3.0. We should have released a new major version with documented breaking changes.

New state is `state.admin.resources[props.resource].data`

Comment: When did we change this? The latest code (https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/07452f0efe31fda3309710f74e11f5988595206c/src/mui/delete/Delete.js#L145) still use state.admin.resources[props.resource].data[
                decodeURIComponent(props.match.params.id)

Comment: In your code, you use `state.admin[props.resource]`. This has been changed to `state.admin.resources[props.resource]`